# I keep getting the error "mysqldump: Got error: 1102: Incorrect database name" when trying to backup databases

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I am trying to back up all the WordPress related databases on the server, but I keep running into this particular error

I am storing all the WordPress databases in a variable name like so

```bash
> databases=$(mysql -u root -p --vertical --skip-column-names -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'wp_%'" | grep -i wp | tr '\n' ' ')
> echo $database # now contains something like wp_1 wp_2 wp_3 ...
```

So in order to back up the databases, I am running this command

```bash
> mysqldump -u root -p --add-drop-database --add-drop-table --lock-tables --add-locks --add-drop-trigger --disable-keys --databases $databases > wordpress_databases.sql
```

But I am getting this error

```bash
mysqldump: Got error: 1102: Incorrect database name 'wp_1 wp_2 wp_' when selecting the database
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Just for your information because I don't know: I tried it in a docker container (official mysql image) and it worked like a charm, even with 14 databases and very long names so that $databases is 309 characters long.

Comment: It sounds like word-splitting of the `$databases` variable is not happening for some reason. Are you sure this is running in bash, not zsh? Have you changed `IFS` or used `set -f` in the script? If it's none of those, see if the variable has any weird/hidden contents by printing it with `printf "databases is '%s'\n" "$databases" | cat -vt` and see if the output shows anything weird.

Answer (score 0):

I think that error is somehow occurred due to the names of some files in the directory where you are running the "mysqldump" command from, Files with names starting with a "dot" or specials characters like it, An update to the used MySQL version can fix the issue or renaming these files and rerun the command, You can have a look at the following post for more info: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57049

Comment: `SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'wp_%'` wouldn't show `.` databases.